# Strange output for Cucumber using JRuby

Tags: cucumber, jruby, gherkin

I am using JRuby 1.6.3 with Cucumber 1.0.2. When I run my feature (jruby -S cucumber features\add_two_numbers.feature) I am getting:

```
Feature: Add two numbers
In order to add not have to use my head
I want to add two numbers
Scenario: Add two numbers←[90m        # features\add_two_numbers.feature:7←[0m

←[32mGiven I have a calculator←[90m      # features/steps/calculator_steps.rb:11←[0m←[0m
←[32mWhen I add the numbers ←[32m←[1m1←[0m←[0m←[32m and ←[32m←[1m2←[0m←[0m←[32m←[90m#features/steps/calculator_steps.rb:18←[0m←[0m
←[32mThen I get ←[32m←[1m3←[0m←[0m←[32m←[90m                   # features/steps/calculator_steps.rb:25←[0m←[0m
1 scenario (←[32m1 passed←[0m)
3 steps (←[32m3 passed←[0m)
0m0.043s
```

What are those numbers with arrow and square bracet in the output? 
How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These codes enable color in the output, but it looks like your system doesn't support them for some reason. You can disable it with the --no-color option.

Answer (score 0):

use this `--monochrome` instead of `--no-color`

For ant build jvn arg add like `<arg value="--monochrome"/>`

else add the same with `@CucumberOptions("--monochrome")`